# I want a script or trigger that would copy the same range from newly added sheets to a "master sheet"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to find a way to copy the following Range E27:R27 everytime a new sheet or previous sheet is edited, I want it to copy the Range to a master sheet named 'March Totals'.

Essentially each sheet besides the 'March Totals' sheet is a daily deposit and I want the Range E27:R27 to copy and past into the next blank row on the March Totals sheet.